# css font property not working

Tags: css, fonts

I´ve been styling my site project with css on dreamweaver.

So far I managed to style the font size, color, alignement, but even thought it all looks fine in the design view of dreamweaver, in the browser it keeps displaying times new romam, wich is not what I wanted. All other properties look fine... 
It doesn't work when on my style sheet is:

> font-family: verdana; <
>   but it works when I add it on the:

```
<div style:"font-family:'verdana'">
```

Any help? 
Thanks...

***UPDATE***

```
#footer {
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F60;
    line-height:50px;
}

.footer {
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:15px;
}

<div id="footer">
<a class="footer"> Blah Blah Blah</a>
</div><!--footer-->
```

This is still displaying times new roman...

Answer (score 3):

'Syntax error?

1.It should be like `<div style="font-family:'verdana'">`

2.Try this

`.footer {
    font-family:'Verdana', Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:15px;
}`

3.If stil doesn't work. Try

`.footer {
    font-family:'Verdana', Geneva, sans-serif !important;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:15px;
}`

4.Also check with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) what styles been applied to element

Answer (score 0):

There might be another font tag that overrides your original font-family tag.

Where are you putting that font-family: tag?  If you want it to be active across your entire document, either attach it to the Body, or some container that encompasses your entire page.

Paste your code if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: I have put the font-family property in both the #div id and .class for the actual text but not working in any...

Comment: Do you have multiple CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

write `font-family` instead of `font` in your css like this:

```
.footer {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: thanks all of you guys... i kinda worked it out now... cheers

Answer (score 0):

or

```
.footer {
    font:16px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

because font-size and font-family values are required.
I suggest to read more about [font property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font) on w3.org

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the `font:` property the wrong way.

The correct way to use is:

```
.footer {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/n7qwA/) that I've put together for you that illustrate the current implementation.